# How to know this is Appstore version or developer version of application

Tags: iphone, ios

Is there any way to know programmatically user is running Appstore version or developer version? Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need to differ between a debug version deployed from Xcode and a release build (ad-hoc or AppStore) you can use the mentioned method of adding a preprocessor macro.
Select your target and select `build settings`, search for `Preprocessor Macros`, under `Debug`you can add e.g. `DEBUG=1`.
In your code you can have functionality conditionally compiled by doing something like this:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
[self enableDebugMode];
#else
[self enableReleaseMode];
#endif
```

Comment: You don't need to set `DEBUG=1` Xcode 4 sets this for the Debug configuration automatically, and has `DEBUG=0` for the Release configuration.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference b/w dev build and app store build is the certificate used to Sign it.

And that can't be obtained programmatically. Instead you can Add a Preprocessor value for the scheme to differentiate it.